# @Scheduled is running twice with spring 4 java configuration

Tags: java, spring, cron

I am using Spring 4.0.2 with Java configuration. There is not an XML configuration.

I have `@Scheduled` annotation for a cron job. It is running twice.  Can someone help me?  This is what I'm trying.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "1 * * * * ?"
```

Comment: And when do you _want_ it to run?

Comment: If it is running twice, you are scheduling it twice. Let me guess you have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` both do component scanning (or worse) load the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

`@Scheduled(cron = "1 * * * * ?")` : Runs your job at 01 second of every (any) minute.

So you job runs once every minute.

**Test:**

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "1 * * * * ?")
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Running Test Run : "+DateTime.now());
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Running Test Run : 2016-06-08T20:06:01.019Z
Running Test Run : 2016-06-08T20:07:01.015Z
Running Test Run : 2016-06-08T20:08:01.013Z
Running Test Run : 2016-06-08T20:09:01.011Z
```

[More info on Spring cron expressions.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)

Comment: Actually When I comment context path in server.xml , it is running only once.